# Launch application before tests on condition

Tags: spring-boot, junit

I have rest-assured tests marked with @SpringBootTest (which allows to start application before executing tests). But I have two use cases:

1. Run tests locally (current setup is ok for that).
2. Run same tests on already running host (not ok, as application is started before executing tests).

Is there any way to sometimes ignore `@SpringBootTest` or somehow turn off application initialization?

Adding minimal example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
//In case service.host provided: no need to run application
@SpringBootTest
public class RestTest {
  @Value("service.host")
  private String host;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(host)) {
      RestAssured.baseURI = host;
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    RestAssured.get("/test").then().assertThat().statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
  }
}
```